# Create a variable by dividing a variable by IQR in Stata

Tags: stata

How could I create a variable by dividing it by an IQR? I have done it through a long way as follows.

Sample data and code is the following:

```
use http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/notes/hsb2, clear

foreach var of varlist read-socst {
   egen `var'75 = pctile(`var'), p(75)
   egen `var'25 = pctile(`var'), p(25)
   gen `var'q =`var'75 - `var'25
   drop `var'75 `var'25
}

gen readI = read/readq
gen sciI = science/scienceq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is just to use `summarize` results directly:

```
sysuse auto, clear

quietly foreach v of var price-foreign { 
    su `v', detail 
    gen `v'q = `v' / (r(p75) - r(p25)) 
}
```

The `egen` route is overkill if it means creating new variables for each original variable, just to hold the quartiles or the IQR as repeated constants. But `egen` comes into its own when you want to do this by groups:

```
bysort foreign: egen mpg_upq = pctile(mpg), p(75)
by foreign: egen mpg_loq = pctile(mpg), p(25)
gen mpg_Q = mpg / (mpg_upq - mpg_loq)
```

Note that the IQR can be 0, and will often be 0 for indicator variables.